# How should I declare pipelines?

Tags: f#

Does it matter how I declare a pipeline? I know of three ways:

```
let hello name = "Hello " + name + "!"    
let solution1 = hello <| "Homer"
let solution2 = "Homer" |> hello
```

Which would you choose? solution1 or solution2 - and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned the pipe-forward operator `|>` helps with function composition and type inference. It allows you to rearrange the parameters of a function so that you can put the last parameter of a function first. This enables a chaining of functions that is very readable (similar to LINQ in C#). Your example doesn't show the power of this - it really shines when you have a transformation "pipeline" set up for several functions in a row.

Using `|>` chaining you could write:

```
let createPerson n =
    if n = 1 then "Homer" else "Someone else"

let hello name = "Hello " + name + "!"

let solution2 = 
  1 
  |> createPerson 
  |> hello 
  |> printf "%s"
```

The benefit of the pipe-backward operator `<|` is that it changes operator precedence so it can save you a lot of brackets: Function arguments are normally evaluated left to right, using  `<|`  you don't need the brackets if you want to pass the result of one function to another function - your example doesn't really take advantage of this.

These would be equivalent:

```
let createPerson n =
    if n = 1 then "Homer" else "Someone else"

let hello name = "Hello " + name + "!"

let solution3 = hello <| createPerson 1
let solution4 = hello (createPerson 1)
```

Comment: but also `let solution5 = createPerson 1 |> hello` can be used?

Comment: @ebb: a better example would be `1 |> createPerson |> hello` - your example works too but only because `1` is a constant

Comment: i.e. this wouldn't work - you'd need brackets again `let solution5 = createPerson 2-1 |> hello` instead `let solution5 = createPerson (2-1) |> hello ` works - you wouldn't need brackets with chaining (i.e. in the revised solution 2). I'm also by no means an expert on this, I'm learning myself - let's get some more input.

Comment: ah, I see :) - but... which of `let solution5 = 2-1 |> createPerson |> hello` and `let solution5 = createPerson 2-1 |> hello` would you prefer?

Answer (score 3):

F# reads from top-to-bottom, left-to-right. For this reason, the `|>` operator is used much more than `<|` as it helps out type inference.

Comment: @J Cooper - Is there any cases where `<|` would be usefull?

Comment: You can sometimes use it to avoid parentheses I guess, like in `if not <| f x y then...`

Comment: I prefer to use `raise <| Exception()` instead of `(raise Exception())` or the backwards looking `Exception() |> raise`